# How to sync bookmarks (favourites) between Google Chrome and Chromium

Tags: chrome, synchronization, bookmarks

I'm new to the world of Raspberry 2 and Linux and I have install Chromium on the Raspberry.  I did this because I thought it would be a good way to access my Google Chrome Bookmarks (Favourites).  However, I'm having problems.  When I log into Chromium in order to sync, I get the message:

> The sync server is busy, please try again later.

I've tried a few hours later, next day, etc.  I suspect the sync server being busy is not the problem.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem and help me sync my bookmarks?

The version of Chromium is:22.0.1229.94.  I vaguely understand it's possible to get a later version.  I'm new to Linux and would have to be told the explicit steps to do so.  The Linux I'm running came with the Raspberry 2 and is some flavor of Debian (I'd report the version number if I knew where to look!).

Finally, I'm not wedded to Chromium.  I just want a browser where I can see
my Chrome bookmarks and (ideally) have them synced every time I add a bookmark to Chrome or the browser on Raspberry.

Comment: I'm the one who wrote this question and originally posted it on the Raspberry Pi group.  It was migrated here by an administrator.  I should mention that the internet is working.  I'm able to get to drive.google and login, get to gmail, etc.   So I guess the fact it was migrated means it is not Raspberry specific?  It would be interesting to know if it is Debian specific.

Comment: It won't be Rpi specific *unless* it has to do with a bug in the ARM port.  It probably isn't really Debian specific either, except to the extent that it may be triggered by their configuration, etc.  I.e., **it's chromium specific,** so you have to figure out why it would say this then go from there.   Which might make it better on [Super User](http://superuser.com/), but beware U&L has a no cross-posting rule (if you don't get an answer here eventually, just delete or ask to close it and try S.U.).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the following manner.
-Go to settings -> advanced settings.
-Click on "add Printer".
After that you will have to sign in by a different page
-insert email and click next.
-insert password and click next.
after that chromium should be synchronizzable. 
You should select the "stay synced" checkbox to be quite for the future.